# How to get correct size of OGRE::RenderWindow after its resize?

Tags: ogre

My program changes the size of [OGRE::RenderWindow](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_render_window.html) at some time and later I want to get the current size of the window. But, when I use `getWidth()` or `getHeight()` on the window, they return the original size of the window.

Example code:

```
OGRE::RenderWindow* win;

// ... OGRE is initialized
// Window is drawn 1024x768 using size from ogre.cfg

// ... lots of code ...

// Window size is changed and it works
win->resize(800, 600);

// ... lots of code ...

// Window is still visibly 800x600, but this call
// returns 1024x768 (the original size)
int w = win->getWidth();  // Returns 1024
int h = win->getHeight(); // Returns 768
```

How to get correct size of the window?

Comment: What Ogre version and what render system? I cannot reproduce the issue in Ogre 1.10 with either OpenGL or Direct3D9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is getActualWidth() and getActualHeight() methods in [Ogre::Viewport](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_viewport.html) class, so you code would look like:

```
Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump();

int w = win->getViewport(0)->getActualWidth();
int h = win->getViewport(0)->getActualHeight();
```

Here we assume that there is only 1 viewport (indexed by 0).

When you use Ogre's rendering loop, you don't have to call this messagePump() as far as I know.